# Applying style to values of only one column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I want apply some filter conditions on specific cols. Based on filter I want to highlight that cell.

[I took this example from another post:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365676/python-pandas-dataframe-and-excel-add-cell-background-color/44365941)

```
styled = (df.style
            .applymap(lambda v: 'background-color: %s' % 'green' if v=='col' else ''))
styled.to_excel('d:/temp/styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

But problem with this is it applies to every cell. So I instead used apply function on a series by converting it to df like below:

```
df['a'] =df[['a']].style
            .apply(lambda v: 'background-color: %s' % 'green' if v=='col' else '')
```

In this case when I export df to excel it gives style object rather than values.

If I dont assign that styled result to `df['a']` and directly convert to excel then I get desired result with style but then i will get only that column and not entire dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`subset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html#Finer-control:-slicing) parameter for specify column(s) for apply styles:

```
f = lambda v: 'background-color: %s' % 'green' if v=='col' else ''
df = df.style.applymap(f, subset=['a'])
```

For negation use [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
df = df.style.applymap(f, subset=df.columns.difference(['a']))
```

Comment: Is negation works in subset ? Like Can I provide one col and it should apply to all col but that

Comment: @EXODIA - Added solution to answer.

Comment: @jezael : We cant apply another style to a styled object ?
Like I apply this background based on one filter

I want to apply n such more style with diff background. And retain all changes.

Comment: Created a new question for that @jezrael
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67869034/styler-object-has-no-attribute-style

Comment: @EXODIA - I think not possible, some kind of merging multiple styles based by conditions. Not sure if possible solution is use `apply` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67534320/2901002)

Comment: @jezael: that is not doing the work correctly.