# Why background_gradient is not working for two different colors?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, seaborn, pandas-styles

I'm trying to put background gradient in different colors for different columns. Why the last color override the one before? What to to do to keep both colors?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
arrays = [np.hstack([['One']*2, ['Two']*2]) , ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B']]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays)
data =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
data.columns = columns 
import seaborn as sns
cm = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)
cc = sns.light_palette("red", as_cmap=True)
data.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm, subset=data.columns.get_loc_level('A', level=1)[0])
data.style.background_gradient(cmap=cc, subset=data.columns.get_loc_level('B', level=1)[0])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each call to [`DataFrame.style`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.style.html) produces a unique styler object. This is so the same DataFrame can be easily styled in different ways without affecting each other.

To apply compounding styles, or multiple styles in general, either store the returned styler as a variable and reuse it:

```
cm = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)
cc = sns.light_palette("red", as_cmap=True)
styler = data.style  # Keep Styler for reuse
styler.background_gradient(
    cmap=cm,
    subset=data.columns.get_loc_level('A', level=1)[0]
)
styler.background_gradient(
    cmap=cc,
    subset=data.columns.get_loc_level('B', level=1)[0]
)
```

Or chain the single styler object:

```
cm = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)
cc = sns.light_palette("red", as_cmap=True)
data.style.background_gradient(
    cmap=cm,
    subset=data.columns.get_loc_level('A', level=1)[0]
).background_gradient(
    cmap=cc,
    subset=data.columns.get_loc_level('B', level=1)[0]
)
```

Both produce styled table:

[image: styled dataframe]

---

Reproducible with seed 5:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(5)
data = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randn(5, 4),
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['One', 'Two'], ['A', 'B']])
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Great answer! Just one more question, is it possible to export these colors to excel? `data.to_excel('colorful.xlsx')` is not working!

Comment: The styled dataframe is a separate object from the dataframe or other stylers. Call to excel on the styler object after styles have been applied. Either `styler.to_excel(…)` or add to the end of the chain.

Comment: you can use an IndexSlice for this: `ix=pd.IndexSlice`, then `subset=ix[:, ix[:, "A"]]` or `"B"`