# How to solve AttributeError when exporting styled Pandas DataFrames as image?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Why do I keep getting the `AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'render'`
when trying to save my Pandas DataFrame as an image?
I made a correlation matrix of the variables in a dataframe through `df.corr()` and stylized it.

```
import pandas as pd
import dataframe_image as dfi
import imgkit

df = pd.read_excel(filename)
CM = df.corr() # CM stands for correlation matrix
styled_CM = CM.style.background_gradient(cmap="Blues")

# either of the following options:
html = styled_CM.render()
imgkit.from_string(html, 'styled_CM.png')

# or this one:
dfi.export(styled_CM, 'styled_CM.png')
```

Both options return the following

> AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'render'

How to work solve this or what alternative to use?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67869034/styler-object-has-no-attribute-style) addresses a similar issue. `styled_CM` is not a CM object, but instead a styler object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Styler object has the `to_html` property:

`html = styled_CM.to_html()` instead of `html = styled_CM.render()`